# j2me: send sms(message) error

Tags: java-me, sms, sendmessage, wma

I am developing an app with j2me polish and for sending sms. I used `javax.wireless.messaging`.
but in some phones such as sony erricson and some emulators, it faces some errors related to this class, Is there any other ways to send sms that is suitable with microedition?
 my code is here and it works well on emulator.

```
private void sendMessage() {
String phoneNumber = "sms://" + mobile;
MessageConnection localMessageConnection = null;
try {
localMessageConnection = (MessageConnection) Connector.open(phoneNumber);

TextMessage localTextMessage =
(TextMessage) localMessageConnection.newMessage(MessageConnection.TEXT_MESSAGE);
localTextMessage.setAddress(phoneNumber);
localTextMessage.setPayloadText(messageTF.getString());
localMessageConnection.send(localTextMessage);
display.setCurrent(getAlertForm("message", "success", null));
} catch (Exception localException) {
display.setCurrent(getAlertForm("message", "failure", null));
}
}
```

microemulator showes this error like some phones:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/wireless/messaging/Message
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.microemu.app.Common.startMidlet(Common.java:412)
at org.microemu.app.Common.initMIDlet(Common.java:1039)
at org.microemu.app.launcher.Launcher.commandAction(Launcher.java:121)
at javax.microedition.lcdui.Display$DisplayAccessor.commandAction(Display.java:189)
at org.microemu.app.ui.swing.SwingDeviceComponent$1.mousePressed(SwingDeviceComponent.java:186)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.microemu.app.classloader.MIDletClassLoader$LoadClassByParentException: javax.wireless.messaging.Message
at org.microemu.app.classloader.MIDletClassLoader.findClass(MIDletClassLoader.java:339)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.microemu.app.classloader.MIDletClassLoader.loadClass(MIDletClassLoader.java:213)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 30 more
```

Comment: please upload the error details i believe it is security exceptions

Comment: I edit my post to show the errors appear.

Comment: `my code is here and it works well on emulator.` may i know in which emulator it is working and in which not ?

Comment: From your log it seems that your org.microemu emulator does not have access to javax.wireless.messaging package. Is it in the emulator classpath?

Comment: re Lucifer:in wtoolkit and kemulator there isn't any problem but microemulator shows this error.

Comment: re Telmo Pimentel Mota: Idon't know, but this error exists in real phones such as some older sonyErricson phones and this is the actual problem; additionally some other apps that work with sms, work well in these phones and I am surprised.